# Can't scrape all elements with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the articles in this web page  but i only managed to scrape the first article, anyone can tell me how to solve this? my code as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


sauce = requests.get('https://www.automobile.tn/fr/neuf/alfa-romeo').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

def find_prices(item):
    price = item.find('div', class_='price').span.text
    return price
    
def find_names(item):
      name = item.find('div', class_='versions-item').h2.text
      return name

articles = soup.findAll('div', class_='articles')
Articlelist= list()
for article in articles:
  
    Articledict= dict()
    Articledict['name'] = find_names(article)
    Articledict['price'] = find_prices(article)
    
    Articlelist.append(Articledict)

  
print(Articlelist)
```

this is the output of my code:

```
[{'name': 'Alfa Romeo Giulia', 'price': '198 000 DT'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue here is that you select with `soup.findAll('div', class_='articles')` only one element, so your loop iterates only once.

**Note** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

To fix that behavior select more specific and use e.g. the container with class "version-item":

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='versions-item')
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.automobile.tn/fr/neuf/alfa-romeo').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res)

data = []

for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='versions-item'):
    
    data.append({
        'name':item.h2.text,
        'price':item.find('div', class_='price').span.text
    })


data
```

###### Output

```
[{'name': 'Alfa Romeo Giulia', 'price': '198 000 DT'},
 {'name': 'Alfa Romeo Stelvio', 'price': '265 000 DT'}]
```